# install module via cpanm in ddev

Tags: panoramas, ddev

I wanted to create a panorama using Marzipano with a FlatView and therefor wanted to use an image which I have to split into different tiles. There is a free open source tool which can do that, called "entile": https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Panotools-Script/bin/entile

Now I'm stuck because it seems that this tool needs to be installed onto a server?

From the install instructions:
To install entile, simply copy and paste either of the commands in to your terminal

cpanm

```
                    cpanm entile
```

CPAN shell

```
                    perl -MCPAN -e shell
                    install entile
```

I already use DDEV for TYPO3 Development on Windows 10 and thought that I can use DDEV for this purpose as well. So I started my TYPO3 Development project (but maybe it's better to use an extra project?) and tried to install the tool.

This is what I got:

```
USER.NAME@my-project-web:/var/www/html$ perl -MCPAN -e shell

CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.
If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each
configuration option instead.

Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] yes

 <install_help>

Warning: You do not have write permission for Perl library directories.

To install modules, you need to configure a local Perl library directory or
escalate your privileges.  CPAN can help you by bootstrapping the local::lib
module or by configuring itself to use 'sudo' (if available).  You may also
resolve this problem manually if you need to customize your setup.

What approach do you want?  (Choose 'local::lib', 'sudo' or 'manual')
 [local::lib] local::lib


ALERT: 'make' is an essential tool for building perl Modules.
Please make sure you have 'make' (or some equivalent) working.


Autoconfiguration complete.

Attempting to bootstrap local::lib...

Writing /home/USER.NAME/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm for bootstrap...
commit: wrote '/home/USER.NAME/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading '/home/USER.NAME/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading '/home/USER.NAME/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Tue, 18 Aug 2020 11:17:03 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
.............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.28) available.
  [Currently running version is v2.20]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


...............................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Reading '/home/USER.NAME/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
DONE
Writing /home/USER.NAME/.cpan/Metadata
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /home/USER.NAME/.cpan/sources/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.00002
4.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Attempting to create directory /home/USER.NAME/perl5

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for local::lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap -- OK
Running make for H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
  HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
  No such file or directory
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@I
NC contains: /home/USER.NAME/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux
-gnu/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28 /u
sr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/li
b/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl/5.28/CPAN/FirstTi
me.pm line 1357.
USER.NAME@my-project-web:/var/www/html$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.20)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install entile
Reading '/home/USER.NAME/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 18 Aug 2020 11:17:03 GMT
Warning: Cannot install entile, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /entile/

to find objects with matching identifiers.

cpan[2]>
```

I don't think that it worked. :/

Entile also needs ImageMagick but I think DDEV already has this included. Not sure if that will work out of the box...

**My questions are now:**
How can I make this work and what did I wrong? Maybe someone can help me with a step by step tutorial?
Do I have to create a new project or can I use an existing one and can something go wrong?

Comment: I think you need to install `local::lib` as it says "you may need to install the local::lib module" in the make failure. After you get the procedure pioneered you'll end up wanting to do this (I think) using a custom Dockerfile, as explained in the docs.

Comment: I don't think entile is in CPAN. That's the reason you're not getting farther. I used the "sudo" technique and got the same complaint. This really isn't a ddev question... it's a question for the maintainer of entile. Or a CPAN/Perl question.

Comment: I also installed cpanm and it's still not found: 
```
$ sudo cpanm entile
! Finding entile on cpanmetadb failed.
! Finding entile () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution entile
```

Comment: I can download a tar.gz archiv from the site above (on the left sitebar) which has a file called "entile" (without any extension) in the /bin/ folder. Do you know if that can be used? If that can be used, that would be good but I have no idea how to integrate that into ddev...

Comment: It really has nothing to do with ddev, and everything to do with perl. You're just trying to use entfile on a Debian computer (the DDEV-Local web image). If you can figure out how to use it from the instructions (just `ddev ssh` to experiment) then it can be installed in a Dockerfile. But it sounds like it might not be maintained...